# more than one interface implemented by class

Tags: java

I have below 2 interfaces.

```
public interface I1 {
    
    public void show();

}
```

Another one

```
public interface I2 {
    
    public void show();

}
```

We have a class which is implementing both.

```
public class Main implements I1,I2 {

@Override
public void show() {
    
    System.out.println("Hello I am mahima");
}
```

I ran the program , there is no compilation or run time error. How can I find which interface method is getting called here? Is there anyway to find it?

This question was asked in an Amazon interview first round.

Comment: It's a trick question.

Comment: How did you run a program without a `main` method? There is no caller of `show()` in the code you’ve posted.

Answer (score 7):

Mu. That one method is the implementation for both interfaces. That `show` you wrote cannot be said to be 'I1's show' vs. 'I2's show'. It's both:

```
I1 i = new Main();
i.show(); // works, prints mahima
I2 j = new Main();
j.show(); // works, prints mahima
```

Comment: ya it is printing same output. But is there anyway to distinguish that, if same method is in 2 interface and i am implementing both so i can decide which one i want

Comment: @Mahima both signatures are identical, so the  decision which you want is meaningless

Comment: @Mahima I have for you a red balloon or a red balloon. Which one do you want? It's a trick question.

Comment: :) :).... I got is @rzwitserloot . thank you so much.